# What kind of independent variables can I use for multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, predictor

I'm very new to statistics. My assignment requires me to use one statistical method taught during lesson so I only have a choice between multiple regression, logistics regression and MANOVA.

My research proposal is to look at the effects of violent video games and aggression. My lecturer suggested me to use multiple regression, so I can look at what factors predict aggression when playing video games.

After reading through several journal articles, I've come out with a few factors that may affect aggression, the types of violent video games played (collaborative or competitive), realism (how much the game relates to reality), family history and gender.

I could set aggression as my dependent variable but I'm not sure how my independent variables could work. Looking at the list of independent variables I came out with, I need to let my participants play a few kind of games (collaborative vs competitive and realism vs non-realism). Then when should I measure their aggression, after they played each game? Wouldn't that make it two dependent variables?

I'm really confused. If there's a way to do this with logistic regression or MANOVA please help me with it too! Thanks!

Comment: Can you have all of your participants play all of the games?

Comment: I can. But the dependent variable is their aggression after they played each game. If I do so, then I would have to measure the dependent variables a few times?

Unless I can use different dependent variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that what you seek to measure is the aggression measure after an individual plays a particular game, rather than some broader measure of overall aggressiveness.

For each of your combinations of games and participants, you will get an additional *value of* the dependent variable of aggression, but these measurements are (ideally) all samplings from the same single *random variable* of your aggression measure. That's the distinction that you might be missing. Make sure to review what you were taught about the nature of random variables.

Multiple regression of the type you envision seeks to find how the *value* of a dependent *random variable* is associated with each of the independent variables. To accomplish this task, you have to measure the *value* of the single dependent *random variable* under a variety of circumstances (combinations of independent variables), as you clearly recognize.

Since you can have each of the participants play each of the games, it will be straightforward to consider the identity of the participant as an independent variable, along with gender, family history, and the characteristics of the game. Your course ideally taught you how to take advantage of this type of experimental design.

Since this is apparently for a course assignment I'll stop the answer here. You will learn this best by doing it yourself. Unless this exercise is part of an exam during which further contact with the lecturer is prohibited, check in frequently with the lecturer to make sure you are not going too far astray. If it is an exam, make sure to talk with the lecturer when all is done to see what you did and didn't understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I realized where I was lost. They didn't taught us about dependent random variable. None of the examples they gave had an independent variable used as between or within subjects. I've tried to do a Google search but I can't seem to find any articles on dependent random variable. Do you happen to have any links about it?

Comment: I'm able to consult my lecturer's help for this assignment. The issue is it's midnight here and I kind of need answers urgently because I don't have much time left to do this. If they didn't taught us about dependent random variable, perhaps it's not ideal to write this in my assignment. I've thought of another way to go about doing this, can you help me see if it's feasible? First, I would ensure both the collaborative and competitive violent video games have the same realism, so that's one extraneous variable removed.

Comment: Then, I'll randomly assigned half the participants to play collaborative violent video game and the other half to play competitive violent video game. This will be my first predictor. The rest of the predictors will be gender and family history.

Comment: After they've played the games, I'll measure their aggression level. In such a case, I don't have to worry about having different dependent variables. Is this method feasible? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see that you have to deal with "different dependent variables" in any case; you just are measuring values of the single "aggression" variable under different conditions. You can split the participants into 2 groups, but you will lose information from how the same person responds to the different types of games.

Comment: But I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: Think about the analysis if you have 2 games and gender as independent variables, split your participants into 2 groups, one group for each game as in one of your comments, and measure aggression for each participant after his/her game. Then your analysis has the aggression measure as the dependent variable, with game and gender as 2 independent variables. If you now have each person do both games, and measure aggression after each game for each person, you still have the aggression measure as the dependent variable, but now can add the individual identities as a third independent variable.

Comment: How do I run SPSS with two different sets of dependent variable?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you don't have two sets of dependent variables. You have one set of values of your dependent variable; each of your dependent-variable values has an associated list of gender, game characteristics, family history, and (for the crossover case where each person does each game) individual identity. SPSS should be able to handle that fine.

Comment: Does it mean in SPSS, for each of the four game types, I will be showing values of their aggression after they played each game?

Comment: Yes. What you seem to want to do is to measure "aggression" after each person plays each game. The "aggression" is the dependent variable, and the associated independent variables are gender, family history, characteristics of the game that was just played, and the individual playing/tested. That said, it's not clear to me how you measure "aggression," but I assume you have some way to do that.

Comment: I'll be using a questionnaire to measure aggression. I understand that we're not supposed to use ordinal values for multiple regression but my lecturer states it's fine. I think I've figured out how to do this. Omg I feel stupid. Just to clarify, I'll have 5 columns in SPSS, subjects (the individual that's playing), game characteristics, gender, family history and aggression values. In my subjects column on SPSS, I can list each participant out four times as they will be trying out all four games. The aggression column will show their respective aggression values after playing each game.

Comment: To run the analysis, I can throw in the aggression value into dependent variable and the rest of the values into the independent variable. However, do I need to put in subjects into the independent variable as well? Thanks again!

Comment: You certainly don't want to throw away the information about the subjects, so you should code them as an independent variable. There are a couple of ways to handle the subjects in the analysis, technically whether they should be treated as "fixed" or "random" effects, and also whether you want to correct for differences among subjects with respect to average "aggression" and/or differences among them with respect to the influences of the games on aggression. Discuss those matters with your lecturer.